# Equipment with two 2.4GHz radios

Tags: rf, antenna, bluetooth

Never even *thought* about this, RF is not exactly my field. However, I need two Bluetooth modules (one is classic, the other low energy, I can't use a single module) on the equipment. I have access to the RF feed of one, and I can design whatever on the other (either connector or PCB trace). The chassis is almost a steel box so internal antennas are a no-go (at least I have a really big reference plane)

What is better?

- Two separate antennas on the case with two separate feeds. However emission lobes would probably interfere somewhat (from what I remember from UHF antennas…)
- A power combiner/splitter to a single antenna. Even with a good isolation between the two ports I'm worried about what would happen when one module is transmitting and the other is receiving: one it's putting out about +3dBm and the maximum input level of the other *should* be +10dBm (it's an nRF52) but maybe it's only a maximum dissipation and the receiver get saturated or whatever

Any experience on such a problem? (no coexistence signals are available of course)

Comment: Do you have full control of the RX and TX timing of both modules?

Comment: what about an rf switch?

Comment: If you use an combiner with decent isolation, the power from one modul to the other shouldn't be a problem

Comment: No control of timing, as I said I've no coexistency signalling. I agree with the isolation. BeB00 how could I switch since I have no idea of when they transmit/receive? BT timing is tricky. OTOH the frequency hopping should help. Thanks for the answers